# Spring + GWT project - execute handler on every user action

Tags: java, spring, gwt, certificate, handler

I'm new one in Spring, GWT and even Java World. So be patient. We have relatively big project, which one used Spring, GWT, Hibernate and Signal-Com Inter-Pro (Russian solution for html form signing to secure identified clients).

So now when user tried to log in into system, it read certificate s/n from http headers, compare with s/n from database. If they are equal, user can work with system. Otherwise, notify user and security administrator.

My current task is to add this check to every user action, i.e. GWT button click, switching to next view and so on. Is there a place where you can organize such a test?

TECH INFO:
Login form have redirect to special page

```
     final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
     form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "checkCertificate.htm");
```

Next, checkCertificate.htm have mapping in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
      bean name="/base_dir/checkCertificate.htm" class="...CheckCertificateController">
          property name="checkSignature" ref="checkSignature"/>
      /bean
```

All necessary certificate actions are implemented in

```
     public class CheckCertificateController extends AbstractController {
         protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     ...
     }
```

which is called when user click login button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a Servlet Filter which performs a security check each time the user needs any information from the database.

Although that's not quite the same as performing a check with each user action, it works pretty effectively for us.

Alternatively you could set up a regular [repeating command](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleFixedDelay%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.RepeatingCommand,%20int%29) which would check at specific intervals and lock the user out if their serial number was invalid.

Comment: Could you give an example of Servlet Filter usage in such way?

Comment: @Maxim it's very simple to use filters like that. If you Google for tutorials on servlet filters you should find several (such as this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). I can't show you exact code because that will depend on your environment.

Comment: I'd setup very simple Servlet Filter. Fine, it works. But I think in this place there are no ways to say GWT to end session.

Comment: System used eventBus approach, when user click log out, this called: eventBus.fireEvent(new LogoutEvent()); (where LogoutEvent extends GwtEvent<LogoutEventHandler>).